# How to get substring of django variable [HTML]

Tags: python, html, django

I have an img element with an src attribute I am trying to format. An example url for would be https://myurl/45/457698373.png, where the 45 is the first 2 characters of the full item.image attribute. My issue is with the {{item.image[0,2]}} part. How do I get the first 2 characters of this item.image ??

```
<img src='https://myurl/{{item.image[0,2]}}/{{item.image}}.png'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django templates do not allow arbitrary Python in them (and Python slices use colons anyway, not commas); what you need here to use Django's template operators.  In this particular example, what you want is

`<img src='https://myurl/{{item.image|slice:":2"}}/{{item.image}}.png'>`